# Weird !=nil check issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, memory-management, uiview

I have a UITableViewController which has a UIView* called errorView that is used to overlay an error message over the table view if a method fails to load web data.

In the init method, errorView is set to nil (0x0 in debugger).

In a load method, called at the end of init AND if a 'refresh' UIButton (on the errorView) is tapped, errorView is compared to nil, and removed from superview and released if it is not nil (Still shows 0x0 in debugger).

In the dealloc method, the same check is done before releasing; but for some reason the variable is never nil even though it hasn't been assigned (0xc000 in debugger) because the data failed method was never called. The app then crashes because it tries to dealloc a null pointer that is != nil.

Example:

```
-(id)init {
    errorView = nil;
    [self Load];
}

-(void)Load {
    if(errorView != nil) {
        [errorView removeFromSuperView];
        [errorView release];
        errorView = nil;
    }

    //Attempt to load data from web
}

-(void)dataFailedToLoad (e.g. UIWebView didFailLoadWithError) {
    errorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame, etc];
    [self.tableView addSubview:errorView];
}

-(void)dealloc {
    if(errorView != nil)
        [errorView release]; //Always crashes because errorView is never nil even though it has been assigned nil?
}
```

I'm pulling hair out over this. The errorView variable IS NOT USED anywhere else but in these methods as described, and everything I can read into suggests it is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Is this the actual code, or a minimal sample? Because you're missing if((self = [super init])) and [super dealloc] calls in your init and dealloc methods...

Comment: it could be that the problem is not with the `errorView` itself. Could it be that you are releasing the `UITableViewController` twice (or more than you are supposed to)? That would cause the `dealloc` method to be called for an invalid `UITableViewController` object that could have garbage on the `errorView` variable.

Comment: It is a very well stripped down version and yes the original does have the routines mentioned. UITableViewController is being released automatically when the view controllers are popped. (And after creating and pushing in the parent view controller)

Comment: it still sounds like something is writing to the memory position where the `errorView` variable is. Are you absolutely sure the `dealloc` is only called once? If that's not the problem, maybe you have some kind of buffer overflow in a piece of memory before `errorView` that is overwriting the value on that variable? Sometimes when variables change their values inexplicably it's actually someone else writing out of their allocated memory positions.

Comment: To try and simplify the problem: surely the only way it could crash at this point is if errorView has been released but not assigned nil? (or never assigned to anything). Neither of these cases are ever true.

Comment: That's not true. Like I tried to tell you, it could crash if you have a buffer overflow (or something like that) that is overwriting the value of the `errorView` variable, or if you have already `dealloc`ed that object when you try to access the `errorView` variable (which according to your comment on the accepted answer is exactly the case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a point of interest; sending a message to a nil object is not an error; a significant number of your checks are completely useless.

Exactly what is going on here is hard to point out without more information; if dataFailedToLoad *actually* is the only place where errorView is assigned, your code should work. However, it's failure indicates that something else is screwing your pooch.

Incidentally, a null pointer that != nil isn't a null pointer.

Comment: My understanding is that the only way to safely check if an object is unassigned is to assign is as nil whenever it is released (or if it is not immediately assigned). And errorView is definately not accessed anywhere else. The problem aroused after adding the errorView functionality.

Comment: Closest answer. Turns out the problem was calling [super dealloc] first and not last in -(void) dealloc

Comment: @Toby Wilson: That's why posting "condensed" code samples is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you called `init` the view doesn't have to be initialized. You should use the standard method `viewDidLoad` to ensure that the view isn't nil.

Comment: The example I've given is simplified. The actual version uses if(self = [super initWithStyle:])

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are talking to the instance you think you are talking to?

I've seen quite a few SO questions that have boiled down to confusion between what the loading of an interface file (xib) instantiates and what the developer needs to instantiate.

I.e. do something like `NSLog(@"%@ %p", self, self);` in all the methods and make sure the address-- the instance-- is the same.